# Help with drivers license number validation regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to validate a drivers license for a form that i am making.
I was trying to use a single regex.

1. Max length 9 characters
2. Alphanumeric characters only
3. Must have at least 4 numeric characters
4. Must have no more than 2 alphabetic characters
5. The third and fourth character must be numeric

I'm new at regex I'm googling trying to work it out. Help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: no im trying to validate a drivers license for a form that i am making. and i have never need to do a regex like this before.

Comment: Yea i was trying to it in a single regex

Comment: use http://regex101.com or http://regexr.com to solve regex-problems, you can try regexes interactivly, they provide a decrypted "what does this regex mean" text and you can play around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to solve this with just one regex is probably a little hard as you need to keep track of multiple things. I'd suggest you try validating each of the properties separately (unless it makes sense to do otherwise).

For example you can verify the first and second properties easily by checking for a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) including all alphanumeric characters and a [quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) which tells that it should be present at most 9 times:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]{4,9}$
```

The [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) `^` and `$` ensure that this will, in fact, match the entire string and not just a part of it. As Marc Gravell pointed out the string `"aaaaa"` will match the expression `"a{3}"` because it can match partially as well.

Checking the fifth property can be done similarly, although this time we don't care about the rest:

```
^..[0-9]{2}
```

Here the `^` character is an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for the start of the string, the [dot (`.`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is a placeholder for an arbitrary character and we're checking for the third and fourth character being numeric again with a character class and a repetition quantifier.

Properties three and four are probably easiest validated by iterating through the string and keeping counters as you go along.

**EDIT:** [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1021362/noob-need-help-with-regex-im-lost/1021382#1021382) has a very nice solution for those two cases with regular expressions as well. Didn't think of those.

If you absolutely need to do this in one regular expression this will be a bit work (and probably neither faster nor more readable). Basically I'd start with enumerating all possible options such a string could look like. I am using `a` here as placeholder for an alphabetic characters and `1` as a placeholder for a number.

We need at least four characters (3) and the third and fourth are always fixed as numbers. For four-character strings this leaves us with only one option:

```
1111
```

Five-character strings may introduce a letter, though, with different placements:

```
a1111
1a111
1111a
```

and, as before, the all-numeric variant:

```
11111
```

Going on like this you can probably create special rules for each case (basically I'd divide this into "no letter", "one letter" and "two letters" and enumerate the different patterns for that. You can then string together all patterns with the [pipe (`|`)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) character which is used as an alternative in regular expressions.

Comment: with this approach, putting it all together, minus step 4, would be a good place to start.  ensuring the limit of two letters could be done after.

Comment: I suspect you'd need ^ and $ for the length test to handle the max length case... "aaaaa" matches "a{3}", for example.

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to be a single regex? I'd keep things simple by keeping them separate:

```
static bool IsValid(string input)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"^[A-Za-z0-9]{4,9}$") // length and alphanumeric
        && Regex.IsMatch(input, "^..[0-9]{2}") // 3rd+4th are numeric
        && Regex.IsMatch(input, "(.*[0-9]){4}") // at least 4 numeric
        && !Regex.IsMatch(input, "(.*[A-Za-z]){3}"); // no more than 2 alpha
}
```

Comment: That was my thoughts exactly. It's easier to read, easier to understand, easier to maintain.

Answer (score 3):

This might get you started...

```
function utilities() {
function validateLicense(stateCode, licenseNumber) {
    // from http://www.uiia.org/documents/license_guidelines_08.pdf
    var oneToSevenNumeric = /^[0-9]{1,7}$/;
    var oneAlpha = /(.*[A-Za-z]){1}/;
    var oneAlphaPlusSeven = /^.[0-9]{7}$/;
    var twoAlpha = /(.*[A-Za-z]){2}/;
    var alphaPlusSixNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){6}$/;
    var threeToFiveNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){3,5}$/;
    var fiveToNineNumeric = /(.*[0-9]){5,9}/;
    var sixNumeric = /^[0-9]{6}$/;
    var sevenNumeric = /^[0-9]{7}$/;
    var sevenToNineNumeric = /^[0-9]{7,9}$/;
    var eightAreNumbers = /(.*[0-9]){8}/;
    var nineNumeric = /^[0-9]{9}$/;
    var nineAlphaChars = /^[A-Za-z0-9]{9}$/;
    var tenNumeric = /^[0-9]{10}$/;
    var elevenNumeric = /^.[0-9]{11}$/;
    var twelveNumeric = /^.[0-9]{12}$/;
    var hPlusEight = /([H][0-9]{8})$/;
    var sevenPlusX = /([H][0-9]{7}X)$/;

    if (stateCode == undefined || licenseNumber == undefined) {
        return "";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AK') {
       return validateExpression(oneToSevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 1-7 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AL') {
      return validateExpression(sevenNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 7 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AR' || stateCode == 'MS') {
      return validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'AZ') { 
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) == true) {
            return "";
        }
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        if (twoAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && threeToFiveNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length < 8) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 Alphabetic, 8 Numeric; or 2 Alphabetic, 3-6 Numeric; or 9 Numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'CA') {

        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && oneAlphaPlusSeven.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha and 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'CO' || stateCode == 'CN' || stateCode == 'CT') {
        return validateExpression(nineNumeric, licenseNumber, "Must be 9 numeric");
    }
    if (stateCode == 'DC') {
        if (sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return  "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'DE') {
        if (oneToSevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 - 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'FL') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha, 12 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'GA') {
        if (sevenToNineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 7 - 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'HI') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || hPlusEight.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 'H' + 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'ID') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || sixNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || (twoAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && alphaPlusSixNumeric.test(licenseNumber))) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 9 numbers or 6 numbers; or 2 char, 6 numbers ";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'IL') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && elevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must 1 character 11 numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'IN') {
        if (tenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9-10 numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'IA') {
        if (nineAlphaChars.test(licenseNumber) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9 alpha numbers";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'KS' || stateCode == 'KY') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha and 8 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'LA') {
        if (nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) == true) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 9 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'ME') {
        if (sevenNumeric.test(licenseNumber) || sevenPlusX.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 7 numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'MD' || stateCode == 'MI' || stateCode == 'MN') {
        if (oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && twelveNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "1 Alphabetic, 12 Numeric";
    }
    if (stateCode == 'MA') {
        if ((oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && eightAreNumbers.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length == 9) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "Must be 1 alpha, 8 numeric; 9 numeric";
    }

    if (stateCode == 'MO') {
        if ((oneAlpha.test(licenseNumber) && fiveToNineNumeric.test(licenseNumber) && licenseNumber.length < 11) || nineNumeric.test(licenseNumber)) {
            return "";
        }
        return "1 alpha - 5-9 Numeric or 9 numeric";
    }
    return "";
}

function validateExpression(expression, value, error) {
    if (expression.test(value) == true) {
        return "";
    }
    return error;
}

return {
    validateLicense: validateLicense,
    validateExpression: validateExpression
};
```

}

Comment: Link in code is down. [Here is what looks like new one](https://www.uiia.org/sites/default/files/documents/license_guidelines_08.pdf).